# How to generate .cod file using blackberry webworks sdk 2.0.0.54?

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

Can we build .cod file using blackberry webworks sdk 2.0.0.54 for a phonegap application?If yes, then plz provide the details as i have generated .bar file that runs properly on blackberry 10 simulators but didn't find any .cod file to test it on blackberry 7 simulator.

Comment: would anyone please explains this issue as i am a beginner so don't know the complete process.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot.

The *.cod format is for the BlackBerry 5.0 - BlackBerry 7 OS, not BlackBerry 10 which uses the *.bar file format.

If you wish to build *.cod files you will need to use the WebWorks SDK for BlackBerry OS: https://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/html5/